# C# ASP arraylist gets cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

first part of my code adds items in an arraylist.

When I later try to access its content by using a for loop, the arraylist gets cleared and does not return any value.

*CODE/FLOW
I first would like to know which events are under a program.
i click on SEARCH button then read from database and place its results into an array.

```
 while (dr.Read())
        {
            string eventID = Convert.ToString(dr["Event ID"]);
            programEvents.Add(eventID);
        }
```

As events are already displayed, I then input person names to register them under an event

```
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < spPeoplePicker.ResolvedEntities.Count; ctr++)
            {
                PickerEntity selectedEntity = (PickerEntity)spPeoplePicker.ResolvedEntities[ctr];
                //get the email of the person added
                //use this email as search tool for Peoplesoft database
                string entityEmail = Convert.ToString(selectedEntity.EntityData["Email"]);
                //string email = Convert.ToString(selectedEntity.EntityData["Title"]);
                //line below can get display name of entity
                PickerEntity pe = (PickerEntity)spPeoplePicker.ResolvedEntities[ctr];

                for (int evectr = 0; evectr <= programEvents.Count; evectr++)
                {
```

THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS.

```
                    paramID = programEvents[evectr];

                    #region getEventDetails
                    ProgramManagement.Conn connect = new ProgramManagement.Conn();
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@connect.getConnString());
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand stmnt = conn.CreateCommand();
                    stmnt.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [TrainingAndScheduling].[dbo].[trainersView]" +
                        " WHERE EventID='" + paramID + "'"; ;
                    SqlDataReader thisReader = stmnt.ExecuteReader();
                    if (thisReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        thisReader.Read();                            
                        eveName = Convert.ToString(thisReader["CourseName"]);
                        eveStart = Convert.ToString(thisReader["StartDate"]);
                        eveEnd = Convert.ToString(thisReader["EndDate"]);
                        eveVenue = Convert.ToString(thisReader["RoomID"]);
                    }
                    else
                    { }
                    thisReader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                    #endregion

                    #region registration for a single event
                    ProgramManagement.Registration register = new ProgramManagement.Registration();
                    if (!register.register(entityEmail, paramID))
                    {
                        //this block is executed if user is not registered
                        errorAdding = errorAdding + "<br/>" + "Engineer: " +
                            pe.DisplayText + " was not registered.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ProgramManagement.Email sendemail = new ProgramManagement.Email();
                        sendemail.sendNotification(entityEmail, pe.DisplayText, eveName, eveStart, eveEnd, eveVenue, paramID);
                    }
                    #endregion
                }


            }
```

Comment: Please provide an example illustrating your problem.

Comment: Please provide the Code Understand Where you Committing Mistake.and Care About this before posting a question.

Comment: Can you please include your code for us?

Comment: any effort of reasearch or googling please?

Comment: code??? Maybe your data is not persistent as you are using web app, make sure you save arraylist between postbacks.

Comment: just included the code. sorry

Comment: where exactly does it fail? Which line of code? Where is your ArrayList? Are you talking about programEvents?

Comment: @fenix2222 yes. programEvents is my arraylist. it fails here

paramID = programEvents[evectr];

Comment: Where is paramID declaration? What exception do you get?

Comment: paramID is a string declared as a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your statement fails is that you are trying to access elements beyond the collection’s bounds. When iterating through `programEvents`, you are assigning indexes to `evectr` ranging from `0` to `programEvents.Count` *inclusive*. However, since indexing is zero-based, the index of the last element is actually `programEvents.Count - 1`; accessing `programEvents[programEvents.Count]` would throw an [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx).

You need to replace:

```
for (int evectr = 0; evectr <= programEvents.Count; evectr++)
{
    paramID = programEvents[evectr];
```

…with:

```
for (int evectr = 0; evectr < programEvents.Count; evectr++)
{
    paramID = programEvents[evectr];
```

Comment: it does not work. does this have something to do with saving it in session?